# Folder Specific sort order?

Tags: finder

Is there a way to set a sort order for a specific folder? My use case is that I have one folder that I frequently access sorted by descending date created but otherwise I generally want all folders sorted ascending by name. Currently each time I go into this folder I need to change the sort order to date created then when I go to any other folder I need to change it back to sort by name. I've set up two function keys to toggle back and forth but was just curious if anyone knew of a way set a specific sort for a single folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to create a shortcut of the folder on desktop to open it in a new window which may retain the order setup ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I just tried it  and unfortunately it didn't work. The sort order changed if I sorted another folder by name.

Comment: I check on Apple Support pages and there should be a presentation option that says ´always open in ´ or something like that.[Look here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/sort-and-arrange-items-in-the-finder-on-mac-mchlp1745/mac)

Comment: Thanks but it seems that applies globally, to all files, and remains until changed.    I change the sort order to date added every time I open the folder.